# WebStorm Node debug closed explicitly error

Tags: javascript, node.js, webstorm

I am trying to debug my node app in WebStorm and keep getting a 'Closed explicitly' error when I start the debug session.

I am pointing my Node interpreter to the version of node installed on my machine and the working directory and index file to the route file of my application.

Note that I am trying to use node version 6.5.0, debug works fine when running against 5.4.0 (for another application).

Be gentle

Comment: not enough info to figure out the issue; please create a support ticket

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when your Nodejs app is immediately exiting (e.g. due to a syntax error), thus it won't accept connections for Nodejs remote debugging.

Comment: How could I check against that?